# Ember.js History with Fullscreen API

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, fullscreen, html5-history

It is possible to use History API with Ember.js, simply by:

```
App.Router.reopen
  location: 'history'
```

But when operating in a fullscreen, any URL modifications breaks fullscreen mode in Chrome (it's well-known bug https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=171670).

Is it possible to queue History API changes in EmberJS, and fire all of them only when the app exits the fullscreen?

P.S. Looks like YouTube do the same – you can watch multiple consecutive videos in the fullscreen, and URL stays the same just until you exit the fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do this by reopening Ember.HistoryLocation. I would try to modify the method pushState to queue paths when in fullscreen. On exiting fullscreen call the pushState method manually with the queued paths.

[Source code for Ember.HistoryLocation](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/lib/location/history_location.js)

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I've extended Ember.HistoryLocation with custom pushState, new property pathQueue and new method fireQueue (which is now listener for screenfull.raw.fullscreenchange in my case). After that I've registered this new class with App.register to use as location in App.Router.reopen.

Comment: Glad it worked. Could you post some code examples? I guess there are more Ember apps which could use fullscreen.

Comment: Sure, but my solution is quite specific (we use CoffeeScript and screenfull.js) and ugly (though there's nothing more permanent than temporary). This is what I've added to the app.coffee – https://gist.github.com/vyahhi/9251106.